# How to access Django based website from different local machines?

Tags: python, django

In the cmd , after receiving my Ipv4 address using **ipconfig** , I have added it to the **ALLOWED_HOSTS** in the **settings.py** file .

Then to run the website , in cmd I ran the following command : 
`python manage.py runserver 192.168.x.x:8000` where 192.168.x.x is my ipaddress .

I am able to to access my website from my own local machine , however on other local machines : 192.168.x.x:8000/ isn't responding.

Answer (score 0):

I fear, there is rather a fundamental misunderstanding of a *local* webserver. The webserver created when you run `python manage.py runserver` is just a programme running on *your* computer. You can make requests against that server in your browser using the address `manage.py` gives you, but that does not mean that the web server was on the internet.

What you expect is like having a Python script `hello_world.py` on your machine and expecting that someone else could just run `python hello_world.py` on *their* machine and it would invoke the script on *your* machine.

If you want to publish your website, you need to host it on a website.

Comment: Along with runserver I am specifying the address I want the particular website to run on. I believe it should be accessible on the other machine with that address itself, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AemieJariwala No. Even if you specify the ip adress of your application when you run `python manage.py runserver`, this is still all running on your local webserver only. This creates only a _local_ webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Aemie,

Try hosting the django server on `0.0.0.0:8000` and attempt to access it from the different machine via the address `192.168.x.x:8000` (the ip address of the host machine IP).

`0.0.0.0` would allow all IPv4 addresses on the local machine to be accessible

Comment: I have already tried that however it doesn't respond from other machines.

Comment: What machine are you hosting from?